# Scripting Engine for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, scripting, javascript.net

I want to allow my users to use a script language to further customize my application.
I´m looking for an embeddable script engine that is thread safe, because it´s a ASP.NET application. I Checked some engines, like Javascript.NET (https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net ) but it is not Thread safe. Other implementations I found do not look stable enough.

Any sugestions ?

Thank you,

Fábio

Comment: JavaScript.Net is thread safe these days, though you'll need to do some of your own locking if you want multiple threads to call into the same instance of the engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps IronPython or IronRuby under the DLR is suitable?

You can mark up your extension points using [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/), and allow scripts to extend your application's functionality.

We've used it successfully in [MahTweets](http://mahtweets.codeplex.com/) (a WPF Application) - but I can't vouch for it's use under an ASP.NET situation.

Of course, thread safety is going to be your least concern if you're allowing random people to run arbitrary code within your application. They'll have full capabilities to completely bypass any security functionality you have, and alter/copy any user data. 
Caveat Emptor..

Comment: Please don´t call my users "random people". They are easily offended :) .

Comment: Sorry, 'Unknown Third Parties' :p

Comment: if you fire up a new AppDomain for running your script engine and set heavy restrictions on it you should be able to lock down the scripting environment pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Lua with something like LuaInterface (http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/). Depending on your level of abstraction and/or freedom for the user writing the script, you may have to refactor a lot of code if you want to introduce a scripting engine.